# grails database commit's during a service's method

Tags: grails

I am trying to have a grails service method which does database commits while running instead of commiting everything at the end.

```
serviceMethode(){
    status = 0
    doFirst
    status = 1
    doSecond
    status = 2
    doThird
    status = 3
 }
```

I am experiencing that 1, and 2 are never persistend to the database, even though I am doing DomainObject.save(flush:true). My guess is that this is due to transaction handling. How can i persist values while the service-method is running rather than at the end of the method.

Comment: Can you turn on sql logging to confirm there are actually no saves? Add `debug 'org.hibernate.SQL'` to your `Config.groovy` `log4j.main` block. Flushes usually work in my experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotate your service method with `@NotTransactional`